# Unix- cut command to extract letters from second word

Tags: unix, cut

So i need to use the cut command on a file of names to get the first letter and then the first 7 letters of the last name
this names are organized as such:
Ann       Arkest

```
cut -c1 ...... realnames > ./shortnames
```

i am unsure  what goes in where i put the ....

Comment: Do you need to use cut?  sed would be so much easier...
 `sed -e "s/^\(.\)[^ ]*\(.*\)$/\1\2/g" realnames > ./shortnames`

Comment: Try this: `cut -c1 realnames>/tmp/names1; cut -f2 -d' ' realnames>/tmp/names2; paste -d '\0' /tmp/names1 /tmp/names2 > ./shortnames; rm /tmp/names1 /tmp/names2`

Answer (score 0):

You can't use use ONLY cut to do this because cut only allows either a list of characters or a list of delimited fields but not both.  So `cut -c1 realnames` gets the first initial and `cut -f2 -d' ' realnames` gets the last name but you can't do it in one command.  You could always use two cuts and write temporary files and then use paste to stitch them back together.  The disadvantage of that is the temporary files and you can't get around that with pipes because paste would need two standard input streams which is not the way things work.

So, with cut and paste:

```
cut -c1 realnames>/tmp/names1
cut -f2 -d' ' realnames>/tmp/names2
paste -d '\0' /tmp/names1 /tmp/names2 > ./shortnames
rm /tmp/names1 /tmp/names2
```

But if you allow programs besides cut (like paste for example) then you may as well just use sed:

```
sed -e "s/^\(.\)[^ ]* \(.*\)$/\1\2/g" realnames > ./shortnames
```

Which is a lot shorter (but not as easy to read).

Comment: i need to get the first 7 letters of the last name. not the entire thing